# draw line using finger and an object will follow that path?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3, gamekit

I m new to game devloping in ios. Now I want made a game similar like **"Control Air Flight"** and **"Air Traffic Controller"** ,

> where a user can draw line using their finger and an object will
>   follow that path

so ,anyone can guide me which is best for developing like this.Can **Cocos2d** is best for it? Or any thing else i have to use for this.

Also If anyone knows of a tutorial already out there or any reference link please suggest me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: hi how u did your task

Comment: Checked the ans which i accepted.It was useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply let the object follow your finger, implement touches (and just one of its methods):

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint toPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    [yourObjectOutlet setCenter:toPoint];
}
```

Here, your object's center will follow your path, but you can adjust its anchor point by editing "toPoint" accordingly to object's frame.

### EDIT

If you want to draw the path, then make the object follow that path, do like this:

```
//define an NSMutableArray in your header file (do not forget to alloc and init it in viewDidLoad), then:
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   //you begin a new path, clear the array
   [yourPathArray removeAllObjects];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint toPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    //now, save each point in order to make the path
    [yourPathArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:toPoint]];
}
```

Now you want to start the move:

```
- (IBAction)startMoving{
   [self goToPointWithIndex:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0]];
}
- (void)goToPointWithIndex:(NSNumber)indexer{
   int toIndex = [indexer intValue];  

   //extract the value from array
   CGPoint toPoint = [(NSValue *)[yourPathArray objectAtIndex:toIndex] CGPointValue];
   //you will repeat this method so make sure you do not get out of array's bounds
   if(indexer < yourPathArray.count){
       [yourObject setCenter:toPoint];
       toIndex++;
       //repeat the method with a new index
       //this method will stop repeating as soon as this "if" gets FALSE
       [self performSelector:@selector(goToPointWithIndex:) with object:[NSNumber numberWithInt:toIndex] afterDelay:0.2];
   }
}
```

That's all!

Comment: As per your ans when I moved my finger the object will also move (its something like object work as pointer).I want to follow the object at particular path which i drawn.Please correct my mistake.

Comment: so you mean you want first to draw the path, then to tap a button that will start the object following that path?

Comment: its working.Just minor change in your code and its done for me..assin pointer to NSNumber ,check spell of intValue.. Thanks a lot for help me..

Comment: yeah, thanks, you were right, I just wrote that code without Xcode's checkspelling. and I'm glad that helped